# How to draw a TE-tree in latex

Tags: diagrams

I want to use Latex to draw this tree as it was not very clear when I bring it to my latex editor

[image: Tree edit distance]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have.  See [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Comment: Thank you very much , I am sorry i did not know abouth that. Now I am going to delete this question because I really do not know how to do these trees at all.

Comment: @lol745 You will have to read a bit about `tikz` to be able to digest code samples that you find here or elsewhere. See e.g. [A very minimal introduction to TikZ](http://cremeronline.com/LaTeX/minimaltikz.pdf) or the [PGF/TikZ manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf).

Comment: @lol745: I've rolled back your edit as it has completely changed the existing question *which has an answer*. If you want to ask something different, or even a related question to this one *which is already solved*, ask a [new question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) or a [follow-up one](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/2117/5764).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a starting point. Many things are self-explanatory; for those which are not, consult first any documentation on `tikz` (e.g., google for 'tutorial tikz'). For any remaining questions feel free to ask here.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  [scale=0.3,circ/.style={circle,draw,minimum width=5,inner sep=0mm,outer sep=0mm}]
  \node[circ,label=above right:$l_1$] (l1) at (0,-10) {};
  \node[circ,label=above right:$l_2$] (l2) at (0,-17) {};
  \draw (0,0) -- (10,-10) -- (7,-10) -- (0,-3)
    -- (-7,-10) -- (-10,-10) -- (0,0);
  \draw (0,-3) -- (l1) -- (7,-17) -- (4,-17)
    -- (l1) -- (-7,-17) -- (-4,-17) -- (l1) -- (l2)
    -- (4,-24) -- (-4,-24) -- (l2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks, this is what I would like to get, I thought this is not from {tiks} .. This answer helps a lot !